# Морфемный состав слова "благотворительный"

Tags: морфемика, морфемный-разбор

В слове "благотворительный" два корня?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

В словообразовательном словаре русского языка (А. Н. Тихонов):
Корень **-благотвор-**; суффиксы **-и-**, **-тельн-**; окончание **-ый**.
(В [этом](https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%83/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) словаре такой же разбор.)

[В морфемно-орфографическом словаре](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?word=on&morph_word=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9):
Корень **-благотвор-**; суффиксы **-и-**, **-тель-**, **-н-**; окончание **-ый**.
(С пометкой: А.Н. Тихонов по непонятным причинам не выделяет в слове «благотворительный» суффикс «н».)

В словаре Т. Ф. Ефремовой:
**благотвори́ть**
*несов. неперех.* Творить благо. Делать добро; благотворительствовать.

Глагол считается книжным, устаревшим (Д. Н. Ушаков), оба слова (*благо* и *творить*) связаны по смыслу очень тесно, возможно, поэтому в современном языке корни слились в единый.
Такая же «метаморфоза» произошла и с некоторыми другими подобными словами: благополу́ч/ный, благослов/и́ть, благообра́з/ный.

Answer (score 0):

**Правильно: благотвор/и/тельн/ый** (в словаре Тихонова).

**Пояснение**

1)  **Почему не выделяем основу БЛАГО**

**БЛАГО.**.. Первая часть **сложных слов**. Вносит зн.: хорошо, добро. Благорасположенный, благомыслящий. Способ образования: **чистое сложение** (благо + расположенный, благо + мыслящий))

**Почему отдельно не выделяют основу БЛАГО** в слове ***благотворительный?*** Нельзя сказать: **благо + творительный**, нет чистого сложения.

Но почему нельзя взять за основу сочетание ***творить благо***? Мы можем сказать: творить добро, зло. Но у слова ***благо*** в словаре только два значения, которые **по стилю или по грамматике** не подходят для  ***творить благо.***

**БЛАГО,**  1. только ед. **Высок.** Благополучие, счастье, добро. Стремление к общему благу. Употребить власть во б. кому-л. Счесть за благо (признать правильным, разумным). **2. только мн.: блага,**  Производство материальных благ.

**Примечание**

Дополненный и уточненный материал по  этой теме можно посмотреть в другом вопросе. [О принципах морфемного анализа, проводимого в школе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449147/%D0%9E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5)

2) Почему выделяем **суффикс ТЕЛЬН**

Суффикс ТЕЛЬН образует прилагательные, мотивированные **глаголом** (наблюдательный, избирательный). Прилагательное ***благотворительный*** образовано от глагола ***благотворить***, а не от существительного ***благотворитель.***

**Словарная цепочка:** благотворить (глагол устар.) — благотворительный — благотворительность.

3) В Интернете можно встретить **два разбора**: выделяется составной суффикс ТЕЛЬН или он делится на два суффикса  ТЕЛЬ + Н. Правильно: составной суффикс ТЕЛЬН.

Но пользователи сомневаются и **неправильно** выделяют суффикс Н отдельно, например:

Внимание! А.Н. Тихонов по непонятным причинам не выделяет в слове «благотворительный» суффикс «н».

[https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?word=on&morph_word=благотворительный](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?word=on&morph_word=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

**Приложение (из словаря)**

БЛАГОТВОРИТЕЛЬНЫЙ, Ставящий своей целью оказание материальной и другой помощи нуждающимся. Б. фонд.  Б. концерт.

БЛАГОТВОРИТЕЛЬНОСТЬ, . Оказание материальной помощи нуждающимся; филантропия. Заниматься благотворительностью. Частная б.

БЛАГОТВОРИТЕЛЬ, м. Тот, кто занимается благотворительностью.

Comment: Мне кажется, что Вы "потеряли" суффикс **и** — он выделяется и у Тихонова, и в других словарях. По Вашей версии корень — _-благотвори-_.

Comment: Да, спасибо, просто забыла выделить. Если исходным является глагол благотвор/и/ть, то откуда возьмется версия с -благотвори-. Не было у меня такой версии, суффикс И выделяют все, этот вопрос нигде не обсуждается.

Answer (score 0):

Начнем с того, что как минимум с исторической точки зрения ответ Sharon неверен.

Благотворительность — это производное от существительного *благотворитель*, восходящего к глаголу *благотворить*. Последний представляет собой кальку (то есть поморфемный перевод) греческого *ἀγαθοποιεῖν*, где *ἀγαθ-* 'добро' + *ποιεῖν* 'творить'.

В связи с этим исторический и актуальный в наше время морфемный разбор — это **благ-о-твор-и-тель-н-ый** (чтобы избежать обвинений в том, что это неправильно, приведу источник, где представлен такой разбор: «Большой универсальный словарь русского языка» под ред. проф. В. В. Морковкина). **Благ-** и **твор-** — два корня, и **творить благо** — совершенно нормально и понятно и, более того, именно так слово (наверняка) интерпретируется носителями языка.

Comment: А точно такой же разбор другого участника, взятый из словаря Тихонова, он правильный? У Вас избирательное голосование? И вариант благ-о-твор-и-тель-н-ый Вы предлагаете школьникам, я Вас правильно поняла? Морфемный разбор соответствует современному состоянию языка, историчность тут ни при чем.http://www.slovorod.ru/der-tikhonov/tih-b.htm

Comment: @Sharon я не говорил, что благотвор-и-тельн-ый — неправильный разбор (хотя он похож на таковой); ваши объяснения, почему не выделяется основа благо-, на мой взгляд, не удовлетворительны, см. выше. Про голосование ничего не понял, а разбор, предложенный мной, может быть использован кем угодно. Морфемный разбор может быть и историческим, и синхроническим.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90593/discussion-on-answer-by-aer----).