# О принципах морфемного анализа, проводимого в школе

Tags: морфемный-разбор

Этот вопрос задан по теме другого вопроса — о морфемном анализе слова ***благотворительный***. [Морфемный состав слова "благотворительный"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449101/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9/449120?noredirect=1#comment459770_449120)

Как известно, существуют **три принципа анализа**:

1) **Правило двойного сопоставления**: «В одном из рядов находится та же основа с другими формальными частями (вертикальный ряд), в другом — та же формальная часть с другими основами (горизонтальный ряд):
(1) храбрость; храбрый; храбриться. (2) храбрец — мудрец, наглец, удалец;

2) Вторым принципом морфемного анализа является принцип **синхронизма**. Исходя из этого принципа, например, мы признаем уже нечленимой основу слова *неделя.*

3) Третьим принципом морфемного анализа является принцип учета **словообразовательных связей** .

[https://шпаргалки.com/russkiy-yazyik-sovremennyiy/190-printsipyi-morfemnogo-173493.html](https://%D1%88%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8.com/russkiy-yazyik-sovremennyiy/190-printsipyi-morfemnogo-173493.html)

Попробуем **применить эти принципы** анализа к слову ***благотворительный*** (определяем количество основ).

**Принцип 1. Правило двойного сопоставления.**

Горизонтальный ряд (слова такой же структуры и способа  образования):

**Две основы** (чистое сложение): благо/расположенный, благо/мыслящий, благо/склонный, благо/разумный.  **Одна основа** (нет чистого сложения): благополучный, благопристойный, благоприятный, благотворительный.

Вертикальный ряд (родственные слова): благотворительный, благотворительность, благотворитель.

**Принцип 2. Синхронизм.**

Благо (согласно словарю) — это в современном языке или высокий стиль, или мн. число (материальные блага).

**Небольшой синхронизм есть**, но он вряд ли оказал существенное влияние, тем более что в словаре прилагательное ***благой*** не имеет стилистических пометок. БЛАГОЙ,  Хороший, добрый.

Поэтому основная причина того, что в слове ***благотворительный*** выделяется общая основа, связана с первым принципом (отсутствием чистого сложения). **Примечание.** Именно этот принцип вызвал наибольшее непонимание в предыдущем обсуждении.

**Принцип 3. Учет словообразовательных связей**: благотворить — благотворительный — благотворитель.

Морфемный состав слова: **благотвор/и/тельн/ый.**

Такой разбор с учетом всех принципов можно назвать **системным**, но есть еще несистемный подход. Выглядит он примерно так. Я вижу знакомые морфемы, я их узнаю без этимологического словаря и просто выделяю их в слове.  Тогда у нас получится такой вариант: ***благ/о/твор/и/тель/н/ый,*** как и было предложено в другом ответе. Чем не вариант, да только для школы он вряд ли подойдет. Там уже проголосовали за систему (другими словами, **выбрали словарь Тихонова).**

**Вопрос:  Верно ли проведен анализ  по приведенной системе и правильно ли сделан разбор слова? Какой разбор (с выделением одной или двух основ) соответствует школьным требованиям?**