# Почему в словах с корнем "благо" выделяют разное количество основ?

Tags: морфемный-разбор

Этот вопрос я адресую в первую очередь  **к педагогам, а также другим участникам,** которые обычно отвечают на вопросы, связанные с морфемным анализом.

Как объяснить, что часть слов с корнем ***благо*** в словаре Тихонова считается сложными (две основы), а другая часть слов имеет одну основу?

Из словаря Тихонова:

**Две основы:** благожелательный, благозвучный, благомыслящий, благонадежный, благонамеренный, благонравный, благоприобретенный, благоразумный,  благородный, благосклонный.

**Одна основа:** благотворительный, благотворный, благочестивый, благочинный, благодушный, благолепный,  благообразный, благополучный,  благопристойный, благоприятный.

Вопрос по данной теме обсуждался на форуме.

[Морфемный состав слова "благотворительный"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449101/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9/449120?noredirect=1#comment459770_449120)

[О принципах морфемного анализа, проводимого в школе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449147/%D0%9E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слова с компонентом **благо-** могут быть образованы сложением нескольких основ (чаще всего двух), одна из которых содержит корень **благ-**: благожелательный (доброжелательный) - тот, кто желает добра; благозвучный (напев)- такой, у которого хороший, приятный (благой) звук. Но очень много сложных слов с компонентом **благо-** как первой частью композиты. Славянская композита - это  готовое сложение или сращение слов, которое образовалось уже в старославянском периоде при калькировании с греческого (при переводе религиозных книг) и было заимствовано русским языком в готовом виде,такая основа считается непроизводной (значение слова не диктуется семантикой корней, в неё входящих - как при образовании фразеологизмов).

Сложное слово с **благо-** церковно-славянский термин: оно служит средством обозначения специального  теологического понятия; его форма принципиальна в древнейший период развития языка: двуосновное образование зачастую семантически тождественно одноосновному слову, пережившему переосмысление в церковном переводном тексте, а затем семантическую деривацию в языке в целом.

*Например, честь - благочестие. Чьсть – "почитание, уважение, достоинство", благо - добро, благополучие в религиозном смысле, вместе получается "уважение, заслуживаемое в результате деяния блага", т.е. **благочьстиЕ  - это "набожность"**. Если бы мы выделили два корня, мы бы определили значение слова как "благая честь" или "благо чести" и не смогли бы понять его терминологический смысл.*

*Благотворительный* (связанный с благотворительностью), ***благотворительность* (оказание материальной помощи из милости)**- корень **благотвор-**  - как будто бы "творение блага, добра". *Благотворный* - "оказывающий благое (хорошее, доброе) влияние **в религиозном смысле, т.е оказывающий милость"**.  Это не всякое добро, а милость к бедным. Значение изменилось.

Композит благо- и корень благ- выступают как универсальное словообразовательное средство при переводе греческих соответствий. Они обладают предельно обобщенной семантикой.

Вот серьёзное исследование на эту тему: http://docplayer.ru/47570982-Leksika-s-kornem-blag-i-kompozity-s-komponentom-blago-v-staroslavyanskom-yazyke-x-xi-vv.html

> Одной из особенностей греческо-славянских параллелей является
>   возможность несоответствия морфологического строения слова оригинала и
>   его старославянского соответствия. В частности, греческим
>   существительным, прилагательными глаголам с непроизводными основами
>   соответствуют в старославянском композиты с благо-, например:
>   благоиzволение — гр. αρετη ‘преимущество, добродетель’ [9, с. 88],
>   благоиспытание — гр. ακρίβεια ‘старательность’ [9, с. 88],
>   благословляти — гр. αινος ‘восхвалять’ [9, с. 89], благодhлие — гр.
>   ωφέλια ‘польза, выгода’ [4, с. 231], благовhрныи — гр. πιστός ‘верный,
>   преданный’ [4, с. 165], благодать — гр. χάρις, χάρισμα [9, с. 86].
>   Вместе с тем встречаются примеры тождественности морфологического
>   строения слов оригинала и перевода: 1) оба соответствия представляют
>   собой композиты, например: благодарити — гр. εύχαριστέιν, благодушие —
>   гр. εύψυχία, благодеть — гр. εύεργεσία; 2) композитой является
>   старославянское соответствие, например: благоиспытание — гр. ακρίβια,
>   благодать — гр. χάρις, 3) оба члена соответствия являются простыми
>   словами, например: благость — гр. χάρις, благъ — гр. καλός, блаженъ —
>   гр. αγιος, μακάριος.

Comment: Людмила, большое спасибо за ответ, очень интересно. Позже я добавлю комментарий.

Comment: Используя понятия композита  и учитывая обобщенность семантики форманта БЛАГО, приведенные слова можно разделить на три группы, выделив те из них, которые сложно истолковать однозначно. Способ их образования тоже неочевиден: есть чистое сложение, есть суффиксальное сложение, а есть образование из словосочетания. В общем, решить эту задачу самостоятельно не представляется возможным, да и словообразовательные словари могут предлагать разные решения.

Comment: И как тут быть школьникам, что должны  писать люди на учебных сайтах? Как доверять словарю Морковкина, если "благотворительный" у него имеет две основы, и как пользоваться словарем Тихонова, который был издан уже давно. Короче говоря, где искать то решение, которое в настоящий момент одобрено в академических кругах и поэтому рекомендовано для использования в школе.

Comment: Для разбора такие слова школьникам не дают, а студенты должны знать, они изучают историческую грамматику. Если нужно определить морфемный состав славянизмов, обращаются к словарям.

Comment: К каким словарям они обращаются? Собственно говоря, меня интересует  реальная  ситуация. Был задан вопрос: сколько основ в слове благотворительный? В двух словарях разные ответы. Я выбираю словарь Тихонова  (одна основа).и получаю минус за ответ, потому что в словаре Морковкина выделены две основы. Так что не совсем правильная у нас образовательная система. Это нельзя давать школьникам (почему это?), а это изучают студенты (лично для себя). Если это будущие педагоги, то зачем им это? Ведь школьникам для разбора они такие слова не дают.

Comment: Это в корне неверный подход. Общую картину должны знать все (здесь неуместны запреты), а специалисты-филологи углубленно изучают свои темы. И не для себя лично, а для людей. Чтобы донести новые знания до тех же школьников, но в популярной обобщенной форме.