# Какими словообразовательными словарями нужно сейчас пользоваться?

Tags: словообразование, морфемный-разбор, словари

Какими словарями нужно сейчас пользоваться (автор, издание)?

Этот вопрос возник при разборе слова ***благотворительный***, а также в связи с разными вариантами разбора слов с корнем БЛАГО у Тихонова (одна основа или две основы).

[Морфемный состав слова "благотворительный"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449101/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9/449120?noredirect=1#comment459770_449120)

[Почему в словах с корнем "благо" выделяют разное количество основ?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449245/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2?noredirect=1#comment459897_449245)

1) У Тихонова несколько словарей разного года, все ли они соответствуют современным требованиям?

Надо сказать, что на большинстве учебных сайтов в Сети дается разбор слова ***благотворительный*** по Тихонову (одна основа).

2) Что вы можете сказать о Большом универсальном словаре Морковкина (2016 год), его используют в школе? Как там разобраны слова с корнем БЛАГО?

https://issuu.com/slovari21/docs/morkovkin_0000_0030

Comment: В указанном словаре Морковкина благотворительный разбирается с двумя основами, а, например, благопристойный - как с одной. Тихоновым не пользовался лет десять, если не больше.